# findByIdAndRemove confirm pop up

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, alert

I want to make the pop-up alert to confirm deleting a comment. But the problem is it deletes the first comment, even if I select any other comments. What I mean is if I have 3 comments of the same user and when I click the delete button on the 3rd or 2nd comment it deletes the 1st comment. I don't know the reason. Without the use of confirm alert, deleting works fine. My attempt is below.

```html
<form id="deletcomment" class="delete-form" action="/home/<%=home._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
<!--<input class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="submit"  value="Delete Comment">-->
 <-- if i use the above with out onclick event it works with out problem -->
<input class= "btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button" onclick="myFunctioncommnt()" value="Delete Comment">
</form>
<script>
  function myFunctioncommnt(){
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete it?")){
           document.getElementById("deletcomment").submit();
          } 
        }
 </script>
```

```html
router.delete("/:comment_id", middleware.checkCommentOwnership,function(req,res){
    //find by id and delete
    Comment.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.comment_id, function(err){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("back")
        }else{
            req.flash("success", "Comment Deleted")
            res.redirect("/home/"+req.params.id);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Only the first element on the page with that id is valid. All others are invalid.

Comment: I am just looking a help here. So how can I make it work for all elements? I have tried searching about confirm pop up but I couldn't get relevant source or I couldn't understand it. How can I use JS for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

i just find an answer to my question for the above. I guess it will be helpful to those of you who are in similar problem like me.
The problem is, we need to assign a unique id to the form so 'document.getElementById' can find the specific comment from database that we want to delete.

```html
<form id="<%=comment._id%>" class="delete-form" action="/home/<%=home._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
<input class= "btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button" onclick="myFunctioncommnt('<%=comment._id%>')" value="Delete Comment">
</form>
<script>
  function myFunctioncommnt(id){
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete it?")){
           document.getElementById(id).submit();
          } 
        }
 </script>
```